# Apply a formula through a function in many columns with different column names of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, formula

I want to use pb2gen function from WRS2 package. It runs a robust t-test against your data and here is its documentation

`pb2gen(formula, data, est = "mom")`

> **formula**    an object of class formula.
>
> **data**   an optional data frame for the input data.
>
> **est**    estimate to be used for the group comparisons: either "onestep"
>   for one-step M-estimator of location using Huber's Psi, "mom" for the
>   modified one-step (MOM) estimator of location based on Huber's Psi, or
>   "median", "mean".

Anyway. The thing is that I'm trying to apply this function on 5 columns of a data frame.

The data frame seems like this

```
| Ge/treat |   Control_1   | Control_2 |  Cancer_1 | Cancer_2 | Cancer_3 | 
|----------|:-------------:|----------:|----------:|---------:|---------:|
| gene1    |       2.65    |    3.01   |   2.20    |  3.65    |   4.01   |
```

and i want to run the t-test between Controls and Cancer.

The formula i want to apply somehow is the `Control_{1,2} ~ Cancer_{1,2,3)`.

I mean I want it to take in mind both Control columns and all of the Cancer ones.

Until now I can run only the t-test for the first column of Control's and Cancer's by running `pb2gen(Control_1 ~ Cancer_1, data= data, est="mom")`.

I'm wondering if it is possible to run the same command by including and the other columns. So any idea or hint is welcomed

Thank you.

EDIT:

I also tried

```
pb2gen(c(Control_1,Control_2) ~ c(Cancer_1,Cancer_2,Cancer_3) , data = data, est="mom")
```

but got

> Error in model.frame.default(formula, data) :    variable lengths
>   differ

Comment: Is it mapply you are looking for maybe?

Comment: Could you suggest a specific way to do that ?

Comment: When you don't know what statistical method to use, you first need to consult a statistician. StackOverflow is for questions where you can specify an appropriate algorithm. (I rather doubt that a t-test makes sense with such repeated measures design.)  It's possible (even highly likely)  that you need to reshape your data. You should probably be corresponding with the package authors or perhaps posting on the BioConductor help forum.

Comment: Of course I know what statistical method to use. And As i described I want to run a robust t-test based on MOM (median of medians). I posted here just for the execution issue that I came across and thought that someone could possibly already solved it. It's a code issue not statistical. I have already talked to the maintainer and actually it is not Bioconductor's package.